# Problems with pod `Firebase/AdMob` in Objective-C project

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, admob, cocoapods

I'm adding pods to my Objective-C projects `Firebase/Analytics` and `Firebase/AdMob` to Podfile and installed them, and then I had some errors:

```
Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/FIRAnalyticsConnector.framework/Modules/module.modulemap:3:10: 
Inferred submodules require a module with an umbrella
```

[image]

Also, I tried to add manually these frameworks but occurred the same errors.

Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '10.0'

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!

target 'Project' do

    pod 'VK-ios-sdk'
    pod 'AFNetworking'
    pod 'CocoaLumberjack'
    pod 'MBProgressHUD'
    pod 'TSMessages', :git => 'https://github.com/KrauseFx/TSMessages.git'

    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics'

    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
    pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
end
```

Xcode: 11.1
Also, the project has Swift bridging file.

Comment: Please show your full Podfile. Also, what version of Xcode are you using? Dropping those two pods into one of my ObjC apps works just fine.

Comment: @Gereon I added Podfile.

Comment: Just dropped this into a newly created ObjC project with one Swift file and the bridging header added, and it works. There must be something else going on with your module-related build settings, I think.

Comment: @Gereon Thanks, I'll try